# How to aggregate between multiple indices in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am using Elasticsearch 5.3.In it, I have two indices, `log1` and `log2`. I want to do aggregation on both of them at the same time. They store different data but share same data for a single field, `sessionId`. In the following query, the fields `location` and `event` are in `log1` and `logEntryTime` and `event` are in `log2`. The field `event` is in both indices but contain different data. the data `INIT` and `EXIT` are present only in `log2`.

```
curl -XGET '127.0.0.1:9200/log1,log2/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  "aggs": {
    "sessions": {
      "terms": { "field" : "sessionId" },
      "aggs": {
        "docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": [ "location" ]
          }
        },
        "event_count": { "value_count" : { "field" : "event" } },
        "events" : {
          "filters" : {
            "filters" : {
              "inits" :   { "match" : { "event" : "INIT" }},
              "exits" : { "match" : { "event" : "EXIT" }}
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "time": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": [ "logEntryTime" ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The purpose of the query is to get the number of events per session id and the corresponding `location` from `log1` and get the `logEntryTime` from `log2` when the `event` is `INIT` and `EXIT`. My query right now does not return any data from `log2`, only the part from `log1` is returning back data.

What is the problem and how to fix it?